# Do I need a try-with-resource on prepared statement creation if all callers make sure to close it?

Tags: java, prepared-statement, try-with-resources

I'm working with some legacy code and it looks like this:

```
    PreparedStatement prepared_statement;
    if (x > 0) {
        prepared_statement = connect.prepareStatement(sql_query);
        prepared_statement.setInt(1, id);

        for (int i = 0; i < list_size; i++) {
            String internal_token_symbol = callMethod(coin, exchange_list.get(i));
        }
    } else {
        prepared_statement = connect.prepareStatement(sql_query);
        prepared_statement.setInt(1, token_id);
    }

    return prepared_statement;
```

The key take away here is that it this creates a prepared statement and then returns it to be used later.  Note that it's not using a try-with-resource or closing if an exception happens.

My question is, if **every** caller of this method uses a try-with-resource, is there any danger here of failing to close the statement?  e.g. if all callers do this:

```
try (PreparedStatement ps = resultOfCallingMyMethod()) {
   // Use the prepared statement
}
```

---

I proved this myself by doing this:

```
@Test
public void testIPrint() throws IOException { // this prints
    try (MyCloseable closeable = new MyCloseable()) {

    }
}

@Test
public void testIAlsoPrint() throws IOException, InterruptedException { //this doesn't print :(
    try (MyCloseable closeable = iThrowAnException()) {

    }
}

private MyCloseable iThrowAnException() {
    MyCloseable closeable = new MyCloseable();
    if (true) {
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }
    return closeable;
}

public static class MyCloseable implements Closeable {
    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException {
        System.out.println("I was closed!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Since try-with-resources guarantees at least an _attempt_ at closing the resource, the only way I can see one _not_ being closed is if (1) closing it fails for some reason; or (2) there is a failure in the method that _creates_ the prepares statement (somewhere in your first code snippet).  It looks like option 2 is certainly possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it would be fine, the only question is: how to ensure that **every** caller is using try-with-resource?

Normally, I try not to leak the PreparedStatement outside of the class. This way it remains class's responsibility to close it.

**Edit:** Actualy, following the Mike Strobel comment: if `x > 0` and `callMethod` throws an exception, it won't be returned to the callers and won't be closed.